# Intent filter for specific string in URI fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

My Android app should open URIs containing specific string in its fragment (part of URI after '#' symbol).

For example:

> http://example.com/page.html#**foo**

I tried the following intent-filter but it doesn't work:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 

    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern="*foo"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Android app should open URIs containing specific string in its fragment (part of URI after '#' symbol).

Android does not support this, sorry. The fragment is not considered to be part of the path, and you cannot filter on the fragment.